# How to display at the top of a Smart banner for Universal Links in Safari

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-association

Implemented Universal link of IOS with iPhone and iPad. My app runs the app by accessing a specific URL in the safari browser. When accessing a specific URL, a Smart banner appears at the top of the web page. This Smart Banner is a smart banner automatically created by AASA (apple-app-site-association).
**AASA**

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "<Team_ID>.<Bundle_ID>",
        "paths": [ "/path/test.asp" ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [ "<Team_ID>.<Bundle_ID>" ]
  },
  "related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "url": "https://example.co.kr/path/test.asp",
      "appID": <Bundle_ID>,
      "appName": name
    }
  ],
  "prefer_related_applications": true
}
```

**Get Url Data**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options {
  self.latestLink = [url absoluteString];
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
      restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
  if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb]) {
    self.latestLink = [userActivity.webpageURL absoluteString];
    if (!_eventSink) {
      self.initialLink = self.latestLink;
    }
    return YES;
  }
  return NO;
}
```

On the iPhone, when you access a specific web page, a Smart Banner is created at the top so you can launch the app through the Open button.
However, on the iPad, you have to access a specific web page and scroll down to see the Smart Banner. This creates a Smart Banner, but it seems to be initially hidden.

Is there a way to make the Smart Banner visible on the Ipade as it is on the Iphone, without scrolling?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [example] showing what you have already tried. See also [ask].

Comment: Added code from `AASA` file. However, universal link is a function that uses xcode's Associate Domain. What I'm curious about is that the 'smart banner', which is automatically created by the 'AASA' file to connect the app and the web, is visible only by scrolling on the 'ipad', but I want to make it visible on the page without scrolling.